# Deducing eq. (39) of Sims (2002)

Tags: macroeconomics, dsge

Here's the [Sims(2002) paper](http://sims.princeton.edu/yftp/gensys/LINRE3A.pdf)

How does one deduce equation (39) from that paper?

Any help would be appreciated.